# Ruby on rails activeadmin i cant find file to change view of input forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I cant find files where i can change inputs in activeadmin, when im making new object.

Where i can find files with view of admin panel.

Comment: Can you add more details about your question? Not clear what's your problem and expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Admin automatically generates forms based on your model's columns but you can edit the form if you want to. For example, if you have a user model that has columns email,name,first_name,last_name, token and so on

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "New User" do
    f.input :email
    f.input :name
    f.input :first_name
    f.input :last_name
    f.input :token
  end
  f.actions
end
```

That code would show email, name, first_name, last_name and token as input fields for the form. In your case, just exclude the token field so that it would not be rendered in the view. You can add this lines of code in your user.rb file under the admin folder in your app folder **project-name/app/admin/user.rb**

This would automatically override the default form for your user model

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAdmin generates form by its own depending on model attributes. If you want to customize the default form you can follow the documentation: 
[documentation](http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html)